# Set hostname on HTTPRequest for testing

Tags: swift, vapor

In writing tests for my Vapor 3 app, I've run into an issue where a certain framework is reliant on checking the incoming requests hostname

```
guard let peerHostName = request.http.remotePeer.hostname else {
            throw Abort(
                .forbidden,
                reason: "Unable to verify peer"
            )
        }
```

It would seem that when testing a request like below

```
let emails = (0...10).map { "email@test.co"}
let responder = try app.make(Responder.self)
let request = HTTPRequest(method: .POST, url: URL(string: "\(usersURI)/create")!, headers: headers)
let wrappedRequest = Request(http: request, using: app)
try wrappedRequest.content.encode(createUserReq)
try responder.respond(to: wrappedRequest)
```

Then the requests hostname is empty and thus an error is thrown. Is there any way I can manually set the hostname of the request? The `hostname` property is get only, so I can't set it that way

Comment: Have you tried putting something like this in your `configure.swift`: `let serverConfigure = NIOServerConfig.default(hostname: "HOSTNAME", port: 9090); services.register(serverConfigure)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to add a 'forwarded' header

```
var headers: HTTPHeaders = [
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            "forwarded": "by=BY;for=127.0.0.1"
        ]
```